# how to exit in the middle of the python program while user press" ctrl+D " for the first time?

Tags: python, exit

```
    import random
    import string
    name=raw_input("what is your name?")
    taunts=['taunts1','taunts2','taunts3','taunts4']
    point = input("Enters the number of points required for a win. ")
    human_p = 0
    computer_p = 0
    selection = ['rock', 'paper', "scissors"]
    
    while human_p < point and computer_p < point:
        computer = random.choice(selection)
        human = raw_input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors ? ")
        print name," selects :", human, "computer selects :", computer
        if computer==human:
            print  name+(" score is %d  computer score is %d  A draw" %(human_p, computer_p))
    
        if (computer == 'rock' and human == 'scissors') or (computer== 'paper' and human == 'rock') or(computer == 'scissors' and human == 'paper'):
            computer_p = computer_p + 1
            print name+(" score is %d  computer score is %d Computer wins" %(human_p, computer_p))
            print random.choice(taunts)
    
        if (computer == 'rock' and human == 'paper') or (computer== 'paper' and human == 'scissors') or (computer == 'scissors' and human == 'rock'):
            human_p = human_p + 1
            print (name+(" score is %d  computer score is %d Human wins" %(human_p, computer_p)))
    
    print("Final score is : %d  %d and computer %d" % (name,human_p, computer_p))
    if human_p == point:
        print ("The overall winner is %d" %name)
    elif computer_p == point:
        print ("The overall winner is Computer")
```

---

## The human player may also end the game by pressing the Control-D sequence at any time.

i dont know what is the code and where to use
it is a sample of rock-paper-scissors

Comment: If the user presses `Ctrl+d` at an input prompt, an exception will be raised that you can catch and do whatever you want.

Comment: how should i implement it?

Comment: @khelwood: It does on *nix, but IIRC Windows uses Ctrl+z rather than Ctrl+d for EOF. So maybe a simple detection of `'\x04'` in the input string will be adequate.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should handle it in your own function (see `get_input`), so that you won't have to handle errors all over your code (try-except, extra indentation... a mess).

For example:

```
import random
import string
import sys
import os

# handle input
def get_input(msg):
    try:
        return raw_input(msg)
    except EOFError:
        print os.linesep + "user quit." 
        sys.exit(0)


name= get_input("what is your name?")
taunts=['taunts1','taunts2','taunts3','taunts4']
point = get_input("Enters the number of points required for a win. ")
human_p = 0
computer_p = 0
selection = ['rock', 'paper', "scissors"]

while human_p < point and computer_p < point:
    computer = random.choice(selection)
    human = get_input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors ? ")
    print name," selects :", human, "computer selects :", computer
    if computer==human:
        print  name+(" score is %d  computer score is %d  A draw" %(human_p, computer_p))

    if (computer == 'rock' and human == 'scissors') or (computer== 'paper' and human == 'rock') or(computer == 'scissors' and human == 'paper'):
        computer_p = computer_p + 1
        print name+(" score is %d  computer score is %d Computer wins" %(human_p, computer_p))
        print random.choice(taunts)

    if (computer == 'rock' and human == 'paper') or (computer== 'paper' and human == 'scissors') or (computer == 'scissors' and human == 'rock'):
        human_p = human_p + 1
        print (name+(" score is %d  computer score is %d Human wins" %(human_p, computer_p)))

print("Final score is : %d  %d and computer %d" % (name,human_p, computer_p))
if human_p == point:
    print ("The overall winner is %d" %name)
elif computer_p == point:
    print ("The overall winner is Computer")
```

Comment: thank you,but why as i press ctrl+d it doesn't exit!:(

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you're not producing an `EOFError` for some reason. What happens when you press `ctrl+d` (what input is given back)? Also, I've edited the answer short moment after posting it, please be sure you have the recent code.

Comment: yeah,i copy the recent code,but it doesnt work for me,actually nothing  happen:(

Comment: How exactly are you running this code? What operating system? What environment?

Comment: pycharm,windows7 ,64bit

Comment: Are you using the debugger, or just running the script? I think Pycharm may take you to debugging once you press ctrl+d. Try running it outside Pycharm.